# Opencart site's Left Side bar Not visible in Mobile Browser

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

I am using opencart 2.0.3.1.

My opencart site is very well accessible in desktop / pc browser. But left side bar is Not visible in Mobile Browser.

I am using default theme.

Not getting any clue what to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Opencart used media query to hide left and right bar in small devices. Opencart used bootstrap class `hidden-xs` for this, After edit stylesheet.css file you can change it.
You can check css effect on your browser after re-sizing your browser window.

Comment: Thank you... But exactly what code lines can I change ? can you give me some sample coding for this ?

Comment: @DrManishJoshi i added few line in my css files and not blocks are visible - 

#column-right.hidden-xs, #column-left.hidden-xs {
  display: block !important;
}
but conditions can be different.